How do I show the status of all ACAs in an Azure ACA Environment
I have an Azure ACA environment up and running with multiple ACA services running in there. I have enabled Azure Monitoring on the environment and push all logs and metrics into a log analytics workspace.
I've looked through the various tables and queries that are available in the log environment, but cannot find a query or other means to show me the current status of all services in the ACA Environment (running, failed etc...)
Is there a Kusto query that can show me the service statuses?

Check this query helps to resolve your issue.

Yes, that seems to work thanks, had to add some stuff to partition and choose the last status, but that works.


How do I show the status of all ACAs in an Azure ACA Environment

Here is the KQL query to check the container app status.
KQLContainerAppSystemLogs_CL
| where EventSource_s =="ContainerAppController"
|where Type_s =="Warning"

Output:

